# Apache JMeter-2.9 it is not connecting/hitting to tomcat server in Eclipse and in Graph Results nothing showing

Tags: jmeter

[After click on Run button JMeter log file[In Graph results nothing showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeRG1.png)

Comment: Probably need more debug information to identify the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your web application in Eclipse it may be the case its context being deployed but no HTTP connectors are being set up to listen to the incoming connections.

Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener so you could see request/response details. My expectation is that all your 150 samplers are failing with "Connection Refused"

Few more tips:

- Upgrade to the most recent JMeter version (2.13 as for the moment) as it has performance improvements, bug fixes and new features
- Once you fix all test and configuration issues [run the actual load test in non-GUI mode](https://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) with all listeners disabled.